# Update reducer A based on reducer B

Tags: reactjs, redux

**Goal:**

Update my favorite colors based on some filters.

**Setting:**

There are two reducers: `filters` and `colors`.

```
export function filters(state = {
  noRed: false,
  noBlack: false,
}, action) { ... })

export function colors(state = {
  red: true,
  black: true,
  blue: true
}, action) { ... })
```

I want to update `colors` based on `filters`. I can dispatch `setFilter` and `setColor` at the same time, but that doesn't work because `setColor` should happen only after `filters` are reduced completely. I can also think of combining `filters` and `colors` together, but I'd like to keep them separated.

What's the best way to achieve my goal? What I really need is something like following:

```
export function colors(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.SET_FILTER:
      // assume I can access filters reducer here
      var filters = filtersReducer
      var colors = applyFilters(state.colors, filters)
      return colors
    case constants.SET_COLOR:
      return action.colors
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Or I can dispatch an action inside the `filters` reducer, but that's an antipattern.

Comment: One usually performs it in the components.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Apply filters to the data in a component.

Comment: What if both the `colors` and `filters` should be placed in a global state?

Comment: So I have `colors`, `currentColors` and `filters` reducers right now. You are saying that I should only have `colors` and `filters` reducers, and should compute `currentColors` inside a component instead?

Comment: That's what I mean, yes.

Comment: @zerkms That actually worked out pretty well! The only problem now is what if I want `filteredColors` in two different components? I have `filterColors` function in componentA and I'd like to reuse it in componentB.

Comment: Multiple options: you may have to perform calculations once in the container then just propagate it further. Or just do it twice in both components.

Comment: 1. Is it possible/conventional for two components to share one container?
2. If not, where should I define `filterJobs` function so that it can be shared by two components?

Comment: Try having a look at this: http://blog.javascripting.com/2016/02/02/encapsulation-in-redux/?utm_campaign=React%2BNewsletter&utm_medium=web&utm_source=React_Newsletter_28

Comment: The rule for my team is: "Reducers never make decisions. They don't decide what should happen, they record what HAS happened."  Conditional logic goes into the action creators, which will sometimes examine the contents of the store in order to determine which action to actually dispatch. That centralizes the logic (rather than putting it out in the components), but keeps the reducers to a single concern. I'm not going to claim that's broadly the best-practice, but it has worked well for us.

Comment: @SMcCrohan I disagree; The only requirement imposed upon a reducer is that it accepts `state` and an `action`, and that it returns a new `state` object - apart from this, one is able to write their reducer in any which manner they please, at least, per the author of Redux.

Comment: Agreed, @lux. What I'm describing is a development practice, not a technical requirement. There's an advantage to having local agreement on how you're going to use a tool that is capable of being used in several ways. Like I said, making no claim that it's the only way to do it - just that it's the approach we took, and it resulted in cleaner code. There are probably plenty of other patterns that would work equally well. That a team discusses it and picks one (any one) is probably more important than WHICH one they pick.

Comment: @SMcCrohan Good point. I can only imagine how muddy reducer logic would begin to look if a team of folks were imparting their own patterns at random. Suppose that never crossed my mind since I'm a team of one in React/Redux land :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Sharing data between slice reducers](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers) official documentation explains clearly.

The `SET_COLOR_BY_FILTER` action will set the filter state first and use the next filter state to set the color.

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';

function filters(state = { noRed: false, noBlack: false }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_FILTER':
            return { ...state, ...action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function colors(state = { red: true, black: true, blue: true }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_COLOR':
            return { ...state, ...action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const colorsByFilters = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_COLOR_BY_FILTER': {
            const filersState = filters(state.filters, { type: 'SET_FILTER', payload: action.payload });
            return {
                filters: filersState,
                colors: colors(state.colors, {
                    type: 'SET_COLOR',
                    payload: { black: !filersState.noBlack, red: !filersState.noRed },
                }),
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const combinedReducers = combineReducers({ filters, colors });

const root = (state, action) => {
    const intermediateState = combinedReducers(state, action);
    const finalState = colorsByFilters(intermediateState, action);
    return finalState;
};

const store = createStore(root);

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('state: ', store.getState());
});

store.dispatch({ type: 'SET_COLOR_BY_FILTER', payload: { noBlack: true, noRed: true } });
```

Output:

```
state:  {
  filters: { noRed: true, noBlack: true },
  colors: { red: false, black: false, blue: true }
}
```